# curl and multi-line get parameter

Tags: curl

I am trying to pass a url-encoded multi-line string as parameter of a GET call to an existing web-service.  I think I am getting quite close to the solution with the following:

```
echo -e 'p_message=a\nb\nc\n' | curl -v -G --data-urlencode @- http://localhost/service
> GET /service?p_message%3Da%0Ab%0Ac%0A%0A HTTP/1.1
```

It seems that the only thing that is going wrong is that the '=' is getting url-encoded.  I am running the latest version of curl (7.33).

Comment: Aren't you just asking `curl` to URL encode the data you give it by using `--data-urlencode`? Passing it readily URL encoded data (the way you like it) and not using the parameter would be obvious solution, right?

Comment: Sure, however that would require an extra component and dependency, but if there is not a neater solution that may be the way I will go (via perl script to url-encode).  However seems I am very close to be able to do this in pure curl, still wonder if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, the following seems to work:

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc\n'" | curl -v -G --data-urlencode p_message@- http://localhost/service
> GET /service?p_message=a%0Ab%0Ac%0A%27%0A HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Congrats for solving that (despite the doubts that I presented), and thanks for posting the solution.